# Protégé: Différent results between DL Query and SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, owl, protege, rdflib, owlready

[Here is a small ontology](http://www.fluxus-virus.com/fichiers/wildlife.owl) called `wildlife.owl`, created by Protégé, in which I have classes `animal`, `carnivore`, `herbivore`, `lion`, `giraffe`, and individuals `Léo` (a `lion`), `Gigi` (a `giraffe`) and `Giginou` (also a `giraffe`). In the ontology I only declare that `lion ⊏ carnivore ⊏ animal`.

When I ask for the instances of `animal` in the DL Query tab of Protégé, I get, among others, `Léo` (which is a `lion`, hence a `carnivore`, hence an `animal`).

But when I write the following SPARQ Query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX me: <file:wildlife.owl#>
SELECT ?b
    WHERE { ?b rdf:type me:animal }
```

I don't get any instance. Same result when I replace `me:animal` by `me:carnivore`. Only when I replace it by `me:lion` I get the desired result `Léo`.

Why is DL Query doing the inference (allowing me to obtain `Léo` as instance of the `animal` class) and not SPARQL Query?

What can I do to get the same result in SPARQL Query?

---

Thanks to the answer by @UninformedUser I now know that I must use the Snap SPARQL Query and not the SPARQL Query.

My next question concerns Python: when I send the SPARQL Query using Owlready2 and RDFlib, again I get no result:

```
from owlready2 import *
from rdflib import *
onto = get_ontology("wildlife.owl").load()
sync_reasoner([onto])
graph = default_world.as_rdflib_graph()
print(list(graph.query_owlready("""
PREFIX rdf-syntax: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX me: <file:wildlife.owl#>
SELECT ?b WHERE {
?b rdf-syntax:type me:animal .
}""")))
```

How can I get this query use OWL Reasoner?

Comment: DL Query Tab uses the OWL reasoner (if enabled), the SPARQL tab not. Snap SPARQL plugin does also use the OWL reasoner, but has some limitation w.r.t. SPARQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks! How can I get Owlreader2 to use OWL reasoner?

Comment: I tried `sync_reasoner()` in the Python Owlreader2 code but nothing changed.

Comment: Within the Python's RDFlib collection of RDF tools is [OWL-RL](https://github.com/RDFLib/OWL-RL) which can do RDFS or RL reasoning but not DL.

Comment: The API is called "owlready2" and not "Owlreader2" - please always check your text before submitting it, otherwise things get confusing.

Comment: And not that it matters, but why the heck are you writing `rdf-syntax:` - everybody is writing `rdf` - please try to stick to common standards.

Comment: Regarding your question: I never used owlready2 in combination with rdflib. Have to try it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the reasoner, Owlready does not retain trivia inferences, such as is-a transitivity (e.g. the fact that lion is an animal).

For trivial inferences, you should rather use SPARQL, as in the example below. The `?any_animal` variable contains all animal subclasses (including `animal` itself), thank to the `SubclassOf*` SPARQL syntax (the `*` indicates transitivity). Then, we take any instance of `?any_animal` class.

```py
    from owlready2 import *
    from rdflib import *

    onto = get_ontology("http://test.org/wildlife.owl")

    with onto:
        class animal(Thing): pass
        class carnivore(animal): pass
        class lion(carnivore): pass

        lion()

    default_world.graph.dump()

    graph = default_world.as_rdflib_graph()

    print(list(graph.query_owlready("""
    PREFIX rdf-syntax: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX me: <http://test.org/wildlife.owl#>
    SELECT ?b WHERE {
    ?any_animal <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>* me:animal .
    ?b rdf-syntax:type ?any_animal .
    }""")))
```

Comment: Thank a lot! I have still a question: among the results I get `[[wildlife.Léo], [wildlife.lion1], [wildlife.Gigi], [wildlife.Giginou]]`, as far as I know there is no individual called `wildlife.lion1`, where does this come from?

Comment: I my example, lion1 comes from "lion()". When creating individuals, if their IRI is not explicitly given, Owlready generates a new IRI by taking the class IRI in lower case, and add a number (starting at 1 as here).